# How to write a c# windows forms application that uses Gmail API?

Tags: c#, winforms, gmail

I find the Google documentation quite confusing.
Any good tutorials about this?

Comment: Could you at least explain which Google API and what you want to use it for? Have you written any code at all?

Comment: pl specify exact api name so that we can help u

Comment: I only used Google API for android BEFORE. tHIS IS UNRELATED.  I Want to be able from my winforms app to inquire about new messages in my Gmail account, tag them and look in them. What's the simplest way to get there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few guides on how to use the Gmail API. The [google document](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet#step_3_set_up_the_sample) explains this pretty well, but it all depends on what you want. [This](http://jason.pettys.name/2014/10/27/sending-email-with-the-gmail-api-in-net-c/) website explains how to send a mail via your program.